# Como implementar um Merge Recursivo

Tags: c

Eu tenho um algorítmo MergeSort e gostaria de implementar a função merge recursivamente, não é o MergeSort recursivo e sim a função Merge dele.
Aqui está o código da Função Merge e do Merge Sort:

```
void mergeInt (int v[], int inicio, int fim)
{
  int meio = (inicio + fim) / 2;
  int i = inicio;       
  int j = meio + 1;     

  int tam = fim - inicio + 1;
  int *aux = malloc (sizeof (int) * tam);   

  int k = 0;
  while (i <= meio || j <= fim)
    {
      if (i > meio)
    {           
      aux[k] = v[j];
      j++;
    }
      else if (j > fim)
    {           
      aux[k] = v[i];
      i++;
    }
      else if (v[i] < v[j])
    {           
      aux[k] = v[i];
      i++;
    }
      else
    {           
      aux[k] = v[j];
      j++;
    }

      k++;
    }

  int l;
  for (l = 0; l < tam; l++)
    {
      v[inicio + l] = aux[l];
    }

  free (aux);
}

void mergeSortInt(int v[], int inicio, int fim)
{
  int meio = (inicio + fim) / 2;

  if (inicio < fim)
    {
      mergeSortInt (v, inicio, meio);
      mergeSortInt (v, meio + 1, fim);

      mergeInt (v, inicio, fim);
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque você quer implementar o `merge` recursivamente?

Comment: É um exercício que eu tava tentando fazer, mas eu n conseguia imaginar a recursividade, acho que pela maneira que o código estava escrito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, montei um teste para o seu código:

```
void mergeSort(int v[], int tamanho) {
    mergeSortInt(v, 0, tamanho);
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {10, 2, 7, 1, 4, 9, 3, 8, 0, 5, 6};
    mergeSort(a, 11);
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui ele funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/UnYQOo)

Antes de transformar o `mergeInt` de iterativo para recursivo, é preciso fazer algumas mudanças para resolver algumas coisas que impediriam a versão recursiva de funcionar:

- Atacar o seu `malloc` e `free`. Mesmo na versão iterativa, usar um monte de `malloc`s e `free`s é um tanto ineficiente, seria melhor usar apenas um em todo o processo do mergesort.
- Retiramos de dentro do `mergeInt`, o último `for` que copia de `aux` para `v`.
- Dentro do `while`, alteramos o `if` para ter apenas dois caminhos possíveis ao invés de quatro.

O código fica assim:

```
void mergeInt(int v[], int inicio, int fim, int aux[]) {
    int meio = (inicio + fim) / 2;
    int i = inicio;
    int j = meio + 1;
    int k = 0;
    while (i <= meio || j <= fim) {
        if (i <= meio && (j > fim || v[i] < v[j])) {
            aux[k] = v[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            aux[k] = v[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSortInt(int v[], int inicio, int fim, int aux[]) {
    int meio = (inicio + fim) / 2;

    if (inicio < fim) {
        mergeSortInt(v, inicio, meio, aux);
        mergeSortInt(v, meio + 1, fim, aux);
        mergeInt(v, inicio, fim, aux);

        for (int l = 0; l < fim - inicio + 1; l++) {
            v[inicio + l] = aux[l];
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int v[], int tamanho) {
    int *aux = malloc(sizeof(int) * tamanho);
    mergeSortInt(v, 0, tamanho, aux);
    free(aux);
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {10, 2, 7, 1, 4, 9, 3, 8, 0, 5, 6};
    mergeSort(a, 11);
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/UK6Uzb)

Neste ponto, observe que a função `mergeInt` se reduziu a ser pouco mais do que apenas um laço `while`. Dessa forma, agora podemos torná-la recursiva.

Os parâmetros `inicio` e `fim` são trocados por `i`, `meio`, `j` e `fim`. A lógica é que `i` e `meio` correspondem a um dos intervalos que será mesclado em `aux` e `j` e `fim` corresponde ao outro intervalo. O `k` também se torna um parâmetro para indicar em que ponto de `aux` a intercalação entre os dois intervalos está acontecendo.

O código fica assim:

```
void mergeInt(int v[], int i, int meio, int j, int fim, int k, int aux[]) {
    if (i <= meio && (j > fim || v[i] < v[j])) {
        aux[k] = v[i];
        mergeInt(v, i + 1, meio, j, fim, k + 1, aux);
    } else if (j <= fim) {
        aux[k] = v[j];
        mergeInt(v, i, meio, j + 1, fim, k + 1, aux);
    }
}

void mergeSortInt(int v[], int inicio, int fim, int aux[]) {
    int meio = (inicio + fim) / 2;

    if (inicio < fim) {
        mergeSortInt(v, inicio, meio, aux);
        mergeSortInt(v, meio + 1, fim, aux);
        mergeInt(v, inicio, meio, meio + 1, fim, 0, aux);

        for (int l = 0; l < fim - inicio + 1; l++) {
            v[inicio + l] = aux[l];
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int v[], int tamanho) {
    int *aux = malloc(sizeof(int) * tamanho);
    mergeSortInt(v, 0, tamanho, aux);
    free(aux);
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {10, 2, 7, 1, 4, 9, 3, 8, 0, 5, 6};
    mergeSort(a, 11);
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/ft0AWL)